# After adding a row in to the repeater, when I refresh page, again that row is being repeated in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I refresh page, again that row is being repeated in datatable .. how to solve this?

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

da1.Fill(dt1);
DataView dv = new DataView(dt1);

rptMatrixs.DataSource = dv;

rptMatrixs.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your code inside:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{ 
// code here
}
```